# calling function on Picker item Selection react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call a `function` whenever i select an item from `picker` and display the selected item with `alert`.
Here's what i am doing :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, Button,Platform,ActivityIndicator, Text, Picker, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
export default class FirstProject extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isLoading: true,
    throttlemode:'',
  }
}
GetSelectedThrottleModeItem=(throttlemode)=>{
Alert.alert(this.state.throttlemode)
}
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.MainContainerAddCamp}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 12}}> Throttle Mode</Text>
    <Picker style={styles.PickerStyleClass}
  selectedValue={this.state.throttlemode}
  onValueChange={(throttlemodeValue, throttlemodeIndex) => this.GetSelectedThrottleModeItem(this.setState({throttlemode:throttlemodeValue}))}>
    <Picker.Item label="Asap" value="asap" />
    <Picker.Item label="Even" value="even" />
    </Picker>
   </View>
  );
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
MainContainerAddCamp :{
flex:1,
margin: 10,
paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 20,
padding: 5,
},
TextInputStyleClass: {
textAlign: 'left',
paddingLeft: 7,
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: '#00BCD4',
},
PickerStyleClass:{
    backgroundColor:'#87ceeb',
    paddingLeft: 7,
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
 borderColor: '#FF5722',
}
});
```

This code is displaying the previously selected value. How can i make it to display current selected value.
Please suggest where i have missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all `setState` method returns nothing. Second after calling `setState` method, you can't know whether state is changed or not, it's because of `setState` method is asynchronous. You can assign a callback to second argument of `setState` method to understand state changes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Alert, Button,Platform,ActivityIndicator, Text, Picker, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
export default class FirstProject extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      throttlemode:'',
    }
  }
  onPickerValueChange=(value, index)=>{
    this.setState(
      {
        "throttlemode": value
      },
      () => {
        // here is our callback that will be fired after state change.
        Alert.alert("Throttlemode", this.state.throttlemode);
      }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainerAddCamp}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 12}}> Throttle Mode</Text>
        <Picker style={styles.PickerStyleClass}
        selectedValue={this.state.throttlemode}
        onValueChange={this.onPickerValueChange}>
          <Picker.Item label="Asap" value="asap" />
          <Picker.Item label="Even" value="even" />
        </Picker>
       </View>
      );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
MainContainerAddCamp :{
flex:1,
margin: 10,
paddingTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 20 : 20,
padding: 5,
},
TextInputStyleClass: {
textAlign: 'left',
paddingLeft: 7,
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
borderColor: '#00BCD4',
},
PickerStyleClass:{
    backgroundColor:'#87ceeb',
    paddingLeft: 7,
marginBottom: 7,
height: 40,
borderWidth: 1,
 borderColor: '#FF5722',
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alert is displaying the old value because it is being called before `this.setState({throttlemode:throttlemodeValue})` is done. So the correct way of doing is

```
GetSelectedThrottleModeItem=(throttlemodeValue)=>{
Alert.alert(throttlemodeValue)
this.setState({throttlemode:throttlemodeValue})
}
render() {
 return (
  <View style={styles.MainContainerAddCamp}>
   <Text style={{fontSize: 12}}> Throttle Mode</Text>
   <Picker style={styles.PickerStyleClass}
    selectedValue={this.state.throttlemode}
    onValueChange={(throttlemodeValue, throttlemodeIndex) => 
    this.GetSelectedThrottleModeItem(throttlemodeValue)}>
    <Picker.Item label="Asap" value="asap" />
    <Picker.Item label="Even" value="even" />
   </Picker>
  </View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use componentDidUpdate to see the selected picker value like this

```
componentDidUpdate(){

this.handlePickerTest();

}

handlePickerTest = () => {

alert(this.state.throttlemode);

}
```